# XPath concatenate multiple nodes but keep as array of cells

Tags: google-sheets

In the sheet I need to retrieve multiple nodes from one `ImportXML` formula some of which use XPath functions like substring(). Therefore I need to use concat() to join them all. But the result is of course the value (the string of connected results) in one cell.

Is there a possibility to keep the result as array?

Eg. `=IMPORTXML("http://w3c.org/","concat(//h3,',', substring-after(//h3/a/@href, '/'))")`

Comment: One more thing -- the XPath question normally returns more than one result but after using substring() it gives only one result. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try split like this. You may need to change what you want to split on.

```
 =split(IMPORTXML("http://w3c.org/","concat(//h3,',', substring-after(//h3/a/@href, '/'))"),",/")
```

Comment: Yeah, the simpliest solution is the hardest one to guess ;)
I thought about retrieving an array as IMPORTXML result but it's good too!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Could you please approve the answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. Thanks.